# How do I send the binary representation through a PHP socket?

Tags: php, sockets, binary

I'm trying to send the binary representation of data through a PHP socket.

So if the number was 15, `socket_write` would send 00001111 as binary representation for 15.

How should I do this?

Comment: The amazing part is, at the interface layer, it gets sent as binary anyway! No need to convert. :D

Comment: @vanneto if you `socket_write($fp, 15)` it will be same as `socket_write($fp, "15")`, I.E. send the bytes `0x31 0x35` whereas as far as I can see he wants to send one byte `0x0F`

Comment: Yeah, sorry for being confusing. I want to send the single byte representation of the data. I was doing socket_write($sock, 15) and it was sending the two bytes, which was confusing me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `chr` function:

```
socket_write( $fp, chr(15));
```

You can also use `\x` escapes with hex values:

```
socket_write( $fp, "\xff\xff\xff\xff" );
```

Would send 4 bytes, with values 255 on each.

Answer (score 2):

To generate a binary representation from arbitrary data use the [`pack()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.pack.php) function.

Example:

```
$data = pack("v", 15); // "i" is unsigned little endian integer
socket_write($socket, $data);
```

See the manual page for more information on the various formats. There's also [`unpack()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.unpack.php) for the reverse functionality.

Comment: this will send `0x0F 0x00`, you want `"C"` to just send `0x0F`

Comment: Well, that's the correct binary representation for an unsigned little endian 16 bit integer. Additionally `C` is not valid for numbers > 255.