# Send Command Message over UDP using PHP

Tags: php, sockets, network-programming, udp

Send Command Message over UDP in PHP

Problem Statement:
I have to send Command Message request over UDP. I don't have any exprience on this. I have interface document like this.

- Sends a command message to UDP port 52005. If the device is active you will receive a response on local UDP
  port 52085.

1) Login Block Request

```
    SOURCE PORT = 52085
    DESTINATION PORT = 52005
    Message Data Structure
    COUNT = 1 byte message padding length 0x09
    TOKEN = 1 byte random value
    SESSION = 2 bytes random value
    COMMAND = 3 bytes command 0x43 0x00 0x00
    PADDING = 9 bytes random data
```

2) Login Block Response

```
    SOURCE PORT = 52005
    DESTINATION PORT = 52085
    Message Data Structure
    COUNT = 1 byte
    TOKEN = 1 bytes save and use for next command
    SESSION = 2 bytes
    TYPE = 1 byte response type 0x63
    INDEX = 1 byte site receiver number
    STATUS = 1 byte receiver status
    BIT0 = network outage
    BIT1 = ping fail
    BIT2 = DTU activity
    BIT3 = host ok
    LOGIN = 1250 bytes login block
    each bit indicates a logged in account 0000 to 9999
    PADDING = 11 bytes random data`enter code here`
```

What I have done is:

a. Tested the UDP connection on testing IP with this code and it is good.

```
<?php
set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {}
function checkUDP($host,$port=80){
    //look no suppression
    $fp = fsockopen("udp://".$host, $port, $errno, $errstr,1.0);
    if (!$fp) {
        return false;
    } else {
        fclose($fp);
        return true;
    }
}

$good = '10.10.2.252';
if(checkUDP($good,52005)){
    echo $good.' Good';
}else{
    echo $good.' Bad';
}

?>
```

b. Created a php file for receive the response on port 52005

```
<?php

//Reduce errors
error_reporting(~E_WARNING);

//Create a UDP socket
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, "0.0.0.0" , 52085) )
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket bind OK \n";

//Do some communication, this loop can handle multiple clients
while(1)
{
    echo "Waiting for data ... \n";

    //Receive some data
    $r = socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 512, 0, $remote_ip, $remote_port);
    echo "$remote_ip : $remote_port -- " . $buf;

    //Send back the data to the client
    socket_sendto($sock, "OK " . $buf , 100 , 0 , $remote_ip , $remote_port);
}

socket_close($sock);
```

c. Created a php file for send message.

```
<?php
error_reporting(~E_WARNING);

$server = '10.10.2.252';
$port = 52005;

if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

//Communication loop
while(1)
{
    //Take some input to send
    echo 'Enter a message to send : ';
    $input = fgets(STDIN);

    //Send the message to the server
    if( ! socket_sendto($sock, $input , strlen($input) , 0 , $server , $port))
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    //Now receive reply from server and print it
    if(socket_recv ( $sock , $reply , 2045 , MSG_WAITALL ) === FALSE)
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    echo "Reply : $reply";
}
```

But when I send any message I didn't get any response. Also I don't have any idea how to verify if I am doing right or not. 
Please help me. Any little info can help. 
Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to debug the device you're communicating with or at least see if it's receiving your message?

Comment: I have no access to the device just have the IP for the testing. I can ask our server admin. But no Idea what to ask. I also can't figure out what message I should send which match the request as per documentation.

Comment: The message looks like it will be just 16 bytes - no text, just numbers (represented in hex in your documentation). I did something a bit similar, though not in PHP. It might be useful to create your own simulated device just to be sure that your UDP messages are coming through at all. Then you can dive into the specifics of the communications protocol.

Comment: @vesan: can you provide any references for this in any language even from command line. How I can send the message can you provide any sample? Thanks for your help.

Comment: That was a long time ago but you can find something similar in PHP in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314438/how-do-i-send-the-binary-representation-through-a-php-socket). Looks like the values you need to send could be (in decimal): 9, 1, 2, 3, 67, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 (though only the 9, 67, 0, 0 seem to be important).

Comment: Thanks mate. You are great!! let me try this. If I stuck then I'll ask you again. :)